# SVN - How to correctly "Update to revision" when current revision has external?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-externals, svn-update

I have a repo checked out on my PC and in rev#244 I added an external to my repo

/src/Common/Build Actions

The "Build Actions" folder is the extenal.

This "Build Actions" folder did exist in the "Common" folder before this untill 244, but not as an external. The "Build Actions" library was a common library that was maintained in a seperate repo, so I decided to bring this in as an external. When I brought it in, I pegged it to a specific revision as well(rev# 29 in this case).

I have being doing a few updates and I am now in rev#250. I wanted to go back to rev#230 to review that code, so I made sure I did not have any uncomitted changes and I went to the root folder (/src) and did update to revision #230 and everything updated correctly except the "Build Actions" folder.

I got "Skipped obstructing working copy" warning for this folder.

So, I did a SVN clean-up followed by another Update to revision and I get the "Build Actions" file from that revision.

1. But is the correct way to Updated to an older revision when an external has been added recently? If not what is the correct way to do this?
2. If a file was not present in rev230, SVN will know to remove it from my working copy, but why dosn't SVN know that rev#230 did not include this external and thus remove it as well?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I would suspect you hit an edge case by going back before there was an external. If you got it to work, you probably went the "correct way". Subversion is extremely reluctant to remove unversioned files (for obvious reasons) so this may explain the no-more-and-not-yet-external directory sticking around.